# Is IOUtils broken these days? It's causing my app to not work

Tags: android, android-studio, ioutils

So I am making a movie list app that parses TMDB for information.

I'm trying to use IOUtils because it makes parsing really easy, but when I put the compile command into the gradle it makes it so that I can't install my app on any phone.

Here is the gradle line:

```
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
```

And here is the error logs I get when that line is present in the gradle:

```
$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/com.jeremy.movieslist"
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]

$ adb shell pm uninstall com.jeremy.movieslist
Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697))
Error while Installing APK
```

It installs just fine on emulators, but on devices it wont even install. Android Studio just gets stuck on "Installing APKs..." for a few minutes and then gives me that error.

Is there anyway to get this working again? I'm a big fan of IOUtils but obviously if it doesn't work on the latest devices than it's useless for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been asked years ago but you can simply use

```
implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0'
```

in the `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).